# Isomorphisms between finite abelian groups and cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

If *G* is abelian of order 175 and *H* is cyclic of order 25 and there is a homomorphism from  *G* onto *H* then what is *G* isomorphic to?

I can see how *G* is isomorphic to either $C_{25} * C_7$ or to $C_5 * C_5 * C_7$. Can there be a homomorphism from $C_5 * C_5$ onto *H* or am I restricted to the $G=C_{25} * C_7$ case (as clearly *H* and $C_{25}$ are isomorphic)?

Comment: Regarding the surjective homomorphism $C_5\times C_5 \to C_{25}$, recall that for finite sets of the same cardinality, surjectivity is equal to injectivity.

Comment: @LokiClock: actually, if $f\colon A \to B$ is an injective map between two finite sets of the same cardinality, then $|f(A)|=|A|=|B|$ so that $f(A)=B$.

Comment: @DanieleA Sorry, I misread that.

Comment: @LokiClock No problem.

Comment: To check that you can guess when an abelian group is a direct product of cyclic groups, you should look at the different equivalent conditions for a group being a semidirect product for one you can apply in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that we always have that $|\varphi(x)|\mid |x|$ (the order of the image divides the order of the initial value. If you had that $\varphi$ was onto, then there would have an $x\in G$ such that $\varphi(x)$ generates $C_{25}$, so we would have $25\mid |x|$. Are there any elements in $C_5*C_5*C_7$ of order divisible by $25$?